# How to set rect on using a native video player when set fullscreenmode to "exactFit" in Livecode?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, video, livecode

My project have video player.

First step:
I create stack and input code:

```
on preOpenstack
   set the fullScreenMode of this stack to "exactFit"
end preOpenstack
```

Second step:
I create picture for play video. When I touch picture. The picture has hide and create native video player

here code:

```
on mouseUp
   lock screen
   set the visible of img "poster" to false
   mobileControlCreate "player", "vdoplayer"
   put the result into pID
   mobileControlSet pID,"filename" , specialFolderpath("engine") & "/vdo.mp4" 
   mobileControlSet pID,"preserveAspect" , true
   mobileControlSet pID,"showController" , true
   mobileControlSet pID,"looping" , loop
   mobileControlSet pID,"rect" , the rect of img "poster"
   mobileControlSet pID,"visible" , true
   mobileControlDo pID,"play"
   unlock screen
end mouseUp
```

This stack size 1024*768. I tested on iPad. The player correct size.But when I tested on iPhone. The player incorrect size.

This picture is before touch image:

[image]

This picture is after touch image:

[image]

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're after...

```
mobileControlSet pID, "rect" , the rect of img "poster"
```

on second thoughts - it looks like that's already in your code - maybe try...

```
set the lockLoc of img "poster" to true
```

it could be getting resized to the images original dimensions at some point

Comment: I'm already this code. "mobileControlSet pID,"rect" , the rect of img "poster""

Comment: apologies - I've already edited the answer.  Try locking the image on the card

Comment: I'm already locking the image on the card. It's nothing changed.

Comment: have you tried setting the player's rect BEFORE hiding the image ?

Comment: Hi John, Kem. I've tested the code out and it works perfectly in my sample sample stack on iPad and iPhone. It would be worth logging the rect that LiveCode thinks your image is. Use 'put the rect of img "poster"' in your mouseUp handler just before you set the rect of the video. You can see the result in the mac console..

Comment: If the rect looks wrong we'll be able to trace the source of the issue more easily.

Comment: I tried follow your suggested.It's correct size.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about trying:

```
mobileControlSet pID,"rect" , the rect of this card
```

Comment: I don't want to set fullscreen. I want to set rect player equal to rect image "poster".