# Controller of player doesn't show after touch done by using a native video player in Livecode

Tags: ios, video, fullscreen, livecode

after I question this : [How to set rect on using a native video player when set fullscreenmode to "exactFit" in Livecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324546/how-to-set-rect-on-using-a-native-video-player-when-set-fullscreenmode-to-exact)

I put this command into the script mine.

```
mobileControlSet pID,"fullscreen" , true
```

After I put this command. I have trouble is when I press the picture, and the picture will disappear and video will play in the full screen, After I press done. Size of video returned to the same as hidden pictures, but Controller of video disappear.

This is all my code.

```
on mouseUp
   lock screen
   set the visible of img "poster" to false
   mobileControlCreate "player", "vdoplayer"
   put the result into pID
   mobileControlSet pID,"filename" , specialFolderpath("engine") & "/vdo.mp4" 
   mobileControlSet pID,"preserveAspect" , true
   mobileControlSet pID,"showController" , true 
   mobileControlSet pID,"fullscreen" , true
   mobileControlSet pID,"looping" , true
   mobileControlSet pID,"rect" , the rect of img "poster"
   mobileControlSet pID,"visible" , true
   mobileControlDo pID,"play"
   unlock screen
end mouseUp
```

----Update

In my card :

```
on playerLeaveFullscreen
   put mobileControlTarget() into pName
   mobileControlSet pName,"showController" , true
end playerLeaveFullscreen
```

It's nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the question is tagged as ios, so this might work ...

```
on playerLeaveFullscreen
  mobileControlSet pID,"showController" , true
end playerLeaveFullscreen
```

(you may have to declare pId to make it available!)

Comment: I put the command as you introduce into my Card. But nothing happened.I update command in the question.

Comment: I solve this problem. My way is, after video back into the same size. I set showController as False and then make it. True in line later.